# No power to my motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, battery, starting, yamaha

I have a Yamaha YZF600 which was running well. I began to have issues starting and had to jump it a few times, so I replaced the battery. After a couple of weeks I finally got the battery and charged it. Now, I have no power.

I get no power to the dash/lights/signals/horn. The only thing that lights up is the green light that indicates I'm in neutral. I have had the battery checked, and it's fine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would possibly think either the ignition switch or you don't completely have the battery attached fully (semi/loose connection at the battery post).

Comment: Could be a ground issue, the neutral light gets it ground in a separate wiring line then the ignition module and lights.

Comment: @chris  What year is your bike?

Comment: It is a 1998...

Comment: Even though the battery is new, have you had it tested?

Comment: Yes, I tooknow it to the auto parts store and they tested it. Said it was reading as a good battery.

Comment: Could it be a blown fuse?